Query all users with multiple conditions on a many-to-many relationship?
I have the following table structure:
user:      user_id|user_name
           1      |John Doe
           2      |Alex

data:      data_id|data_kind|data_value
           1      |123      |Hello
           2      |456      |World
           3      |123      |GoodBye
UNIQUE(data_kind, data_value)

user_data: user_id|data_id
           1      |1
           1      |2
           2      |3
           2      |2
UNIQUE(user_id, data_id)
INDEX(data_id)

How would I be able to query all users (John Doe) which have (data_kind=123,data_value='Hello') and (data_kind=456,data_value='World') ?

Even if there's a unique constraint in the data table, the many-to-many
relationship table user_data does not prevent multiple rows of data related to the same user.
To be safe against potentially duplicate data, the query can take the form:
select *
from user u
where exists (
  select 1 from user_data ud
  join data d on d.data_id = ud.data_id
  where ud.user_id = u.user_id
    and d.data_kind = 123 and d.data_value = 'Hello'
) and exists (
  select 1 from user_data ud
  join data d on d.data_id = ud.data_id
  where ud.user_id = u.user_id
    and data_kind = 456 and data_value = 'World'
)


I don’t know if I understood correctly but a single user can have more than one data with the same data_type. so John Doe could have for example (data_kind=123,data_value=‘xyz’). Is the unique still wrong?

The data model does not prevent John Doe to be related twice to the data (123,Hello)... or thrice.

Oh I see now, sorry :p

Actually, wouldn’t that be blocked on the UNIQUE(data_kind,data_value) of the table data?

I stand corrected. You are right.
